# Use @everyone in power automate

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate, power-automate-desktop, power-automate-custom-connector

I am new to power automate, I would like to mention @everyone when Keywords are mentioned in MS Teams

I tried but it rendered as text instead of a command that would notify everyone in MS Teams group chat.

What can I do to make this possible?

Comment: Currently it is not possible to @everyone using power automate. You can suggest this feature at https://ideas.powerautomate.com/d365community/forum/086dd68e-597f-ec11-8d21-0022482e8f9f

Comment: Would it be possible via the Graph API? Might just be a different type of chatMessageMention resource type or chatMessageMentionedIdentitySet resource type, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessagementionedidentityset?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: No, @everyone is not possible with Graph API as well.